# Bang! pocket and expansions

Tags: expansions, bang

I'd like to ask two questions regarding bang!

1. Is bang! pocket sold elsewhere? Or just in Brazil? I could not find it in amazon.com, so I guess it only exists here.
2. Are there any expansions compatible with bang! pocket. I am thinking that card sizes would be incompatible between bang! pocket and the normal-sized edition.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of this "Bang! Pocket" edition before and admittedly there isn't a lot of it going on on the Internet either - this very question is the fourth result in Google and the first three are in Portuguese. This leads me to think that it is indeed specific for Brazil.

Due to the lack of information on the card sizes, I can't tell if these cards are compatible with the expansions, but the graphic looks very similar. Normal sized Bang! cards are 87 mm × 56 mm, so if yours are also this size there shouldn't be any compatibility issues.

Hope that helps :)